# Returning a flash message for validation and succes from AJAX from submission using Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am of the understanding after doing research that JSON is used however I am unsure of the processes. The code below is my AJAX the console log after.done is not currently working however it was working when I had success as part of the AJAX object.

**AJAX**

```
      $(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
      var wrap = $(this).closest('div.form_wrap');
      wrap.find('form').each(function() {

          var id = $(this).prop('id');
          var arr = jQuery.makeArray( "#"+id );
          var url = $(this).attr('action');
          var type = $(this).attr('method');
          var i = $('#'+id); // Or just $(this)
          var data = i.serialize();

    // setup on submit 
          i.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formElem = $(event.currentTarget);

    console.log(data);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

              $.ajax({
                  type        : type, 
                  url         : url, 
                  data        : data,
                  dataType    : 'json',
                  encode      : true
                })
                  .done(function(data) {              
                      console.log(data);         
                  });     
        });

        i.submit();
      });
        });
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //validate
        $this->validate($request, array (
            //'exercise' => 'required|unique:workout_goals,user_id,NULL,id,exercise,'.$request->exercise,
            //'reps' => 'required|integer',
            //'exercise' => 'required|unique:workout_goals,exercise,NULL,id,user_id,'.$request->user_id,          
        ));

        //store
        $post = new workout_shared;
        $post->date = $request->date;
        $post->user_id = $request->user_id;
        //$post->shared_id = $request->shared_id;
        $post->exercise = $request->exercise;
        $post->weight = Input::get( 'weight' );
        $post->reps = $request->reps;
        $post->sets = $request->sets; 

        //save
        $post->save();


        //session flash message
        Session::flash('success','Workout shared!');

        //redirect


        return back();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.done will only be called after a successful ajax call, so you are probably receiving an error while calling that url. Use $.fail to catch this error:

```
$.ajax(...)
 .done(function(){ console.log("Done!"); })
 .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
    console.log("Fail!", jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); 
 });
```

Setting a Session::flash() will store this message in the session for the next http request, to retrieve this message use this on the next page displayed:

```
Session::pull(...)
```

However as you are calling with ajax you will need to return the message as JSON as you said. I would also recommend something along the lines of this to deal with your save method, and then implement either a flash message or json depending on how the method is called:

```
...

// Save 
$result = $post->save(); // return a boolean for success/fail
$message = $result ? "Workout shared!" : "Workout sharing failed!";

// Response
if ($request->ajax())
{
    // Ajax response, will translate to JSON
    return new Array(
       'Success' => $result,
       'Message' => $message
    );
}

// Regular Http response
Session::flash('save-response', $message);

// Redirect
...
```

A further step would be to extract the entire response section of this code to a new method, which could then also be used after validation, such as:

```
WorkoutSaveResponse($result, $message)
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, I am having a problem processing could there be a Syntax error as all js files are failing to load.

Comment: I have removed new from `return new array` and everything is processing. Last problem is the session message is not displaying.

Comment: Are you receiving any data in your .done() callback? You may need to:
return Response::json([
       'Success' => $result,
       'Message' => $message
]);

This should return an object here:
.done(function(response){
  console.log(response, response.Message)
  // use this message to manually display a flash message
})


Another way to deal with this would be to reload or redirect the page on success then pull the flash message from the session on page reload (you would need to move the Session::flash(...) above the return after saving)

Comment: I am and can display alerts and console logs, how do I display the flash message as HTML?

Comment: As you are using JQuery something along the lines of: $('#flash-message').show().html(response.Message)

Comment: We must be close it is now returning:
response is not defined

Comment: Does your .done() callback look like this?
`.done(function(response){ $('#flash-message').show().html(response.Message); }`

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)